# Using XSLT variable in X PATH string

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I have an XPath string as follows:

```
/results/server[@name='server1']
```

I would like to construct a new XPath using a previously defined XSLT variable:

```
/results/server[@name='$server']
```

I haven't tried 'concat' might be possible with that. I am using XSLT 2.0. XSLT parser complains if I use the string as defined above:

XPST0003 XPath syntax error at char 65 on line 89 near: Unexpected token "" in path expression

Comment: What do you mean, "complain"?  All that looks valid to me (even if the string containing a dollar sign is probably not what you want.) Any error message?

Comment: NEVER tell us that something gives you an error (or "complains") without telling us what the error is. We like to help, but not when people seem to be wilfully holding back the relevant information.

Comment: XPST0003 XPath syntax error at char 65 on line 89 near {...q $currentHost]/hardwareSta...}:
    Unexpected token "<eof>" in path expression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refer to the variable anywhere in the XPath expression:

```
/results/server[@name eq $server]
```

If you write it with quotes, `'$server'`, then it is just a string literal that happens to contain a dollar sign.

Comment: I get a syntax error using that format. Here is the string: `<xsl:variable name="PATH" select="/summary/results/server[hostname eq $currentHost]/hardwareStats/"/>`

Comment: Your expression ends with a path operator (aka a slash), which is invalid. That is indeed a syntax error.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - I didn't think it was even possible to put XSLT variables into xpaths... based on reading this http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/nono.html#d1874e40

Comment: It is different. In your question, you want to use a variable in an expression.  In Dave's FAQ, it is about building an expression as a string and evaluating it dynamically (taking the specific example of an expression being a variable reference, like the string containing `'$server'`). Dynamic evaluation is like the `eval` in many languages (and [xsl:evaluate](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#dynamic-xpath) in XSLT), but this is not what you want here.